# PHP Flat File Website Hierarchy

Tags: php

I am trying to figure out a way of organizing a php multidimensional array with the different pages and organized by parent and child. I was considering just using a flat file rather than a MySQL DB.

Would it be possible to organize it so that I can include a php file near the top of the content section of a site that would dynamically print the current page and its parent pages in a similar way like this?

Home >> About >> Meet the Team

Thank you!

Comment: Make nested array with the structure of the website, serialize it (or json_encode) and store in flat file. When needed - read, json_decode or unserialize, find path and print it out.

Answer (score 0):

You could always store the name of the current page on a variable at the top of your file and then do something like this:

```
[php]
$page = "About";
$descrip = "About the Team";

[html]
<ul>
  <li>Home /</li>
  <li> <? echo $page; ?> / </li>
  <li> <? echo $descrip; ?> / </li>
</ul>
```

A quick solution but effective